# Isolate dart - Should I do create only one Isolate for application? Work like pub sub over topic name

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

Isolate dart - Should I do create only one Isolate for application? When need just send data then do in background, then send back to UI thread ?
We can use Isolate run or compute every time we need, But I got lag app in some case if call a lot of Isolate run , compute with milliseconds interval.

So I try to do this : https://github.com/badpaybad/dart_isolate_pool

IsolatePubSubServe will register function to do inside Isolate. register function to handle result and it should run in UI thread.
Functions register discovery each other by topic name. Work similar to pub sub

Is it the good way to use one Isolate ( singleton ) in application ?

eg: code usage

```
var pubsub = IsolatePubSubServe.instance; // as singleton
// or create new one IsolatePubSubServe();

print("------- add new DoInBackground, new DiBuilder AfterInit spawn");

// should register in initState
await pubsub.AddBackgroundFunction("test2", (args, diCollection) async {
var diTest2 = diCollection["Test2Di"];
//this func will be called in Isolate.spawn, can reuse class inited in DiBuilderFunction 
//do your logic need run inside spawn, no UI thread
return [args, diTest2];
});
// should register in initState
await pubsub.AddDiBuilderFunction("test2", () async {
  //this func will be called in Isolate.spawn, init class for background function do late. 
// it just run one time for each topic, no UI thread
var mapDI = <String, TestObjectResult>{};
mapDI["Test2Di"] = TestObjectResult();
return mapDI;
});
// should register in initState,
await pubsub.AddOnResultFunction("test2", (p0) async {
  //UI thread, if mounted setState
print("Test2 resutl include DI $p0");
});
// should call to pass data to bg function do. 
// eg: touch button send data, just support args similar to Isolate sendport.
await pubsub.Publish("test2", ["a", 1, "b"]);
```

Create only one Isolate for application. Register functions to do inside Isolate, register result functions to handle result. Functions discovery each other by topic name. Is it the good way to use only one Isolate as singleton in app?